# Outsource Junit Before Method

Tags: java, junit, abstract

Abstract Test

```
public abstract class AbstractTest

User user;

@Before
public void before(){
    user = new User();      //wanna run this method in TestA, TestB, ...
}
```

Extending test

```
public class TestA extends AbstractTest

User user;

@Test
public void testUser(){
    AssertTrue(user.test);
}
```

Of course the user is not initialized. How I can initialize the user using the `@Before`-method from the `abstract` test class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the field only in AbstractTest and make it protected, so that child test classes (regardless of the package they're in) can access it:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest

protected User user;
...
```

Do not re-declare the field in child classes.